# How to use cordova localization plugin

Tags: cordova, localization

After reading the Readme I'm still not sure how to use this Cordova localization plugin (https://github.com/kelvinhokk/cordova-plugin-localization-strings). Could anyone be so kind as to point me to an example? Thanks in advance.

I already made a file called en.json in my PROJECT_ROOT/translations/app directory, but don't know what I should put in my html file to make the localized strings appear in my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this particular plugin is **not** used for localizing html files, only to "manage string files that you need natively" on iOS or Android, such as NSCameraUsageDescription, and to "localize your app name on both iOS and Android", as the README says.